# Twig - how to natively display RedBean relationships inside template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, redbean

I'm trying to get symfony's *Twig* to play nicely with *RedBean*.

I can display a top-level bean's data, but none of its relationships.

Here's what I mean:

In my controller, I'm calling Twig in a standard way (somewhat psuedo code):

```
// Controller
$vars = array(
    'people' = R::find('person')
);

return $this->app['twig']->render('index.twig',$vars);
```

My beans are structured as follows:

```
PERSON
->id
->first_name
->last_name
->company <-- (this represents a 'company' bean)

COMPANY
->id
->name
```

Inside *index.twig*, I can easily output the person's name like this...

```
{% for person in people %}
    {{person.first_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

... but what I WANT to be able to access is the associated company bean, like this...

```
{% for person in people %}
    **{{person.company.name}}**
{% endfor %}
```

How do I do that from inside a twig template without requiring additional controller/model logic?

Comment: I have not tried RedBeans inside of S2 but it seems like it would work.  Verify that "echo $person->company->name" gives the expected result.  It's possible that your relations are not setup correctly?

Comment: It works as expected from inside the controller... i.e. echo $person->company->name works fine. It's just inside the TWIG file that it's not. I even set-up a print_r filter ({{person|print_r}}) and the twig template is correctly identifying the 'person' var as a RedBean_OODBBean Object... but person.company is coming up as null. Very odd!

Comment: Twig works by looking for actual instance data or method names.  RedBeans hide this stuff behind magic methods.  You could try adding a getCompany() custom method http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual/custom_getters but I don't think that will help.  Other than wrapping the person bean into an accessor object of some sort, I don't really see a solution.

Comment: @Cerad - excellent suggestion, that actually worked perfectly! I just added a getCompany() method to the bean and returned $this->company inside the method. To call it, it now just requires {{person.getCompany().name}} -- not quite as clean and it does require explicit methods, but at least it works... thanks Cerad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows the basic problem:

```
protected function testQuery()
{
    $persons = \R::find('personx');
    foreach($persons as $person)
    {
        //$person->company;

        if ($person instanceof \ArrayAccess && isset($person['company']))
        {
            echo 'Got Array' . "\n";
        }
        echo get_class($person) . ' ' . $person->name . ' ' . $person->company->name . "\n";
    }
}
```

What is happening is that company is lazy loaded when you do $person->company.  Twig checks for the existence of the company property before attempting to load it and does not find it.  If you uncomment the $person->company line then the test passes and all will be well.

I didn't see anything in RedBeans to allow eager loading.  You could have your controller run through and just call $person->company on each person.  Or you could try messing with Twig_Template::getAttribute(); Or maybe even use the queries and work with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive my necro-posting, but this is the only page on the Internet about this problem, and I think I have a more elegant solution than the accepted answer (which may not have been possible at the time the question was posted).

I realize the OP didn't want to create extra model functionality, but this solution is a minimum of 4 lines - so not a lot of work.

I created a model wrapper for my bean, then referenced the related bean in the `open()` method.  `open()` gets called automatically when `R::load()` gets called for the related table.  So for the OP's situation, the model would look like:

```
class Model_Person extends RedBean_SimpleModel{
    public function open(){
        $this->ownCompany;
    }
}
```

Simply referencing `ownCompany` triggers the lazy loading, which now allows Twig to access the property.

Comment: So does $person->open() get called automatically somewhere?  I have not looked at redbean since the original post.  Just curious.

Comment: Yes, open() gets called whenever R::load() is called on the related table.  I've updated my answer to clarify this.

Comment: this is perfect for my purposes, thank you! didn't find anything anywhere else either.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{% for person in people %}
    **{{person.__get('company').name}}**
{% endfor %}
```